# Disable apache proxy if resource exists on the server

Tags: php, apache, reverse-proxy

How can I serve a file if it exists and only proxy the request if it does not?

At the moment I have the following code that is able to proxy the requests, but that's about it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName proxytest.xxx.com
    ProxyPass / http://somedomain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://somedomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `ProxyPassMatch` directive

For example to pass all none existing gif file requests to the proxy - you can ofcourse use any regex you like:

```
 ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*\.gif)$ http://backend.example.com$1
```

See documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch).